# layer.featureCount returns 0 even though features are present

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers

I create a new shapefile with a plugin, no problems. But when I use the `layer.featureCount()` function in QGIS in the **Python Console**, it returns 0 even though there are features.
[image]

So far I have found two solutions:

1. restart QGIS
2. selecting all manually then using `layer.selectedFeatureCount()`

But is there a way to fix the problem without selecting it manually?

The part of the plug that creates the shapefile:

```
        fn = self.dialog.filename_edit.text()
        layerFields = QgsFields()
        layerFields.append(QgsField('point_id', QVariant.Int))            
        layerFields.append(QgsField('point_name', QVariant.String))       
        layerFields.append(QgsField('sec_id', QVariant.Int))        
        layerFields.append(QgsField('tag_name', QVariant.String))   
        layerFields.append(QgsField('sec_level', QVariant.Int))     
        layerFields.append(QgsField('boundary_v', QVariant.Double))  
        layerFields.append(QgsField('recovery_t', QVariant.Double))   
        layerFields.append(QgsField('regular_fl', QVariant.String))    
        layerFields.append(QgsField('activation', QVariant.Double))     
        layerFields.append(QgsField('osm_id', QVariant.String))     
        
        writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(fn, 'UTF-8', layerFields, QgsWkbTypes.Point, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(self.dialog.crs), 'ESRI Shapefile')
        feat = QgsFeature()
        
        inputValues = {"name":[], "sec_id":[], "tagList":[], "lon":[], "lat":[], "osm_id":[]}
        
        #Multiprocessing 
        with Pool(10) as p:
            all_sectors = p.map(self.query, searchList)

        max_lenght = 0
        for sector in all_sectors:
            sector_result, sec_id, tagList = sector
            sector_lenght = 0
            for result in sector_result:   #goes through all results of a sector
                sector_lenght += len(result['elements'])

                for element in result['elements']:    #goes through all elements in the tag
                    tag_name = tagList.pop(0)
                    
                    if 'center' in element:
                        lon = element['center']['lon']
                        lat = element['center']['lat']
                    else:
                        lon = element['lon']
                        lat = element['lat']

                    if 'tags' in element:
                        if 'name' in element['tags']:
                            name = element['tags']['name'] 
                            name = name.replace(" ", "_")      
                        else:
                            name = tag_name
                    
                    typ = str(element['type'])
                    id = str(element['id'])
                    osm_id = typ +"/"+ id

                    pt = self.dialog.coordinateTransform(lon,lat,False)

                    if self.dialog.geom.contains(pt):
                        inputValues['name'].append(name)
                        inputValues['sec_id'].append(sec_id)
                        inputValues['tagList'].append(tag_name)
                        inputValues['lon'].append(lon)
                        inputValues['lat'].append(lat)
                        inputValues['osm_id'].append(osm_id)
            if sector_lenght >= max_lenght:
                max_lenght = sector_lenght
        
        num = 1
        new_tag_name = ""
        old_sec_id = ""
        outputValues = self.checkValues(inputValues)
        multiplier = len(str(max_lenght))
        for feature_count, (name, sec_id ,tagList, lon, lat, osm_id) in enumerate(zip(outputValues['name'], 
                                                        outputValues['sec_id'], 
                                                        outputValues['tagList'], 
                                                        outputValues['lon'], 
                                                        outputValues['lat'],
                                                        outputValues['osm_id']), 1):   
            if sec_id != old_sec_id:
                old_sec_id = sec_id
                idx = 1
            idx_sec = sec_id * (10**multiplier)
            idx_num = idx_sec + idx
            idx += 1
            
            if tagList != new_tag_name:
                new_tag_name = tagList
                num = 1
            if name == new_tag_name:
                name = f"{name}_{num}"
                num += 1    

            pt = self.dialog.coordinateTransform(lon,lat,False)
            feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(pt))
            
            feat.setAttributes([idx_num, name, sec_id, tagList, 5, 0.2, 14, "true", 0, osm_id]) 
            writer.addFeature(feat)

        layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer(fn, '', 'ogr')
        del(writer)
```

Comment: I couldn't find `layer.featureCount` in your script.

Comment: I don't use `layer.featureCount` in the script. This code creat only a shapefile. I use `layer.featureCount` in an other plugin.

Comment: Could it happen that the other plugin opens the layer before the features have been flushed on disk with `del(writer)`?

Comment: @user30184 how should this be possible if I use `layer.featureCount()` manually via the console after the plug-in is finished?

Comment: In this example also updateFields() is used https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/ but probably del(writer) does it by the same.